# JQuery UI Tabs activate event is not firing

Tags: jquery-ui

```
var activeTab = $('#tabs ul li[name=<%= this.activeTab %>]');
var activeTabIndex = activeTab.length > 0 ? activeTab.index() : 0;
$("#tabs").tabs({
  selected: activeTabIndex,
  create: function (e, ui) {
    alert('create!');
    console.log("create!");
  },
  activate: function (e, ui) {
    alert('here!');
    console.log("test");
  }
});
```

The activeTab variable is meant to activate the same tab after POST (it works).  The create event is firing as expected.  But the activate event is not, and I don't understand why.  I'm obviously missing something.

I'm using the following for documentation:

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Small skeleton of the tabs div.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
  <li name="Admin"><a href="#admin-tab">Admin</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your html?

Comment: I'm not going to provide the html for the following reasons.  1.  The tabs are working properly, including the successful calling of the create event.  2. The html is probably a good 400-500 lines long, interspersed with asp.net tags.

Comment: If you feel there is something specific that could be causing issues in the html, let me know and I'll double check.  Otherwise, I'm confident that the html is correct since I'm seeing no javascript errors, and everything except this 1 single event is working properly.

Comment: Is your jQuery selector correct? Does debugging tell you that it's undefined?

Comment: The selector is correct.  The activateTabs variable you see finds the tab that was used for the POST and resets it.  If the selector were not correct, this bit of functionality would not work, but I've tested and it's definitely working.

Comment: I've added a small skeleton of the html.  The opening div tag and the li tag were copy/pasted for accuracy.

Comment: What are you expecting should happen? When/why should the `activate` event fire?

Comment: I expect the activate event to fire when I click on a new tab.  ie, when it's not "active" and I make it active via a mouse click.  And if that's not the correct behavior, I would like to know how to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in a SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35173/discussion-between-shadowcat7-and-fred).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Determine what version of jQuery UI you are using. Since you are using 1.8, you must use `show` instead. See the [jQuery UI 1.8 docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/#event-show).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort, I didn't even consider that the documentation I was looking at wasn't accurate.